# Ender 3 nozzle moves through previous layer on lithophane

Tags: creality-ender-3, z-axis, nozzle, bigtreetech

I'm trying to print lithophanes and having an issue with the nozzle moving through the previous layer and basically "drawing" through the print.

I've printed 3 lithophanes before with zero issues. Here are the settings for those:
0.4 mm nozzle

- PLA
- Temperatures

  - nozzle temperature 210 °C
  - bed 70 °C
- 0.12 mm layer height
- manual bed leveling
- 30 mm/s speed
- stock Ender 3 mainboard

Here's the settings for the prints I'm doing now with the 0.2 mm nozzle:

- PLA
- Temperatures

  - nozzle 210 °C
  - bed temp 70 ° C
- 0.12mm layer height
- BLTouch auto bed leveling
- 20 mm/s speed
- BigTreeTech mainboard

Here's what I've done and looked at to fix it:

- Calibrated extruder
- manual bed leveling, then ABL
- calibrated Z offset
- checked for flat spots on rollers, there are none
- tried including a Z hop with little success.

I've referenced the following articles without solving the problem.
[Nozzle rubs on previous layers](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/nozzle-rubs-on-previous-layers)

[Ender 3 nozzle gets closer and closer to the previous layer as the print progresses](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13358/ender-3-nozzle-gets-closer-and-closer-to-the-previous-layer-as-the-print-progres)

Below are the two lithophanes, the first one successful and the second the failure. I have tried going back to the 0.4 mm nozzle and the old settings but I'm getting the same failures. The biggest difference is the mainboard switch and adding the BLTouch. I don't have any issues with my other prints (more traditional 3D models) only lithophanes. Any help and ideas would be appreciated.

[image: successful lithophane]

[image: failed lithophane]

Comment: lithoophanes are printed standing, not laying.

Comment: Wouldn't it tip over from being too thin? Every reference I've seen has it lying flat on bed.  I tried to generate supports in Cura and supports would barely touch it and didn't branch out far enough.

Comment: in any case, the lower print does show a lot of overextrusion. like... wrong steps/mm setting.